# which is the best way to check whether the element is present using protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have used the below protractor code to check whether the element is present .

```
this.check_textbox_is_present=function(textbox_locator)
     {
         expect(element(by.model(textbox_locator)).isPresent());

         //which one is best above line or below to check element is present
         expect(element(by.model(textbox_locator)).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
     }
```

Having said that if use the second statement which is below it throws error saying  "  Expected false to be truthy. "

```
expect(element(by.model(textbox_locator)).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the above are ways to find the element visibility on Web page, as per my experience **isPresent** some times not working properly.

The best ways to check visibility of element and which works 100% perfect is protractor.ExpectedConditions

Code Snippet:

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;

this.check_textbox_is_present=function(textbox_locator)
{
    var elementToBeCheck=element(by.model(textbox_locator);
    expect(EC.visibilityOf(elementToBeCheck).call()).toBeTruthy();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vojtech Ruzicka, your solution works great.

Comment: One more question is it just the same above  principle we should use for checking an element is disabled or enabled.in protractor